# React, wait for a hook to finish before starting another hook

Tags: reactjs

I have a component like follows

```
export const Component = () => {
  const { data: item} = useItem();
  const { list } = useItemList(item?.id.toString());


  return(
    item ? (<p>some stuff</p>) : (<p>loading</p>)
  )
}
```

Problem is the app is not waiting for item to be available and it runs useItemList while its undefined, but i've to wait to fetch item

How can I solve so?

Comment: you can check for value of item before doing  ```const { list } = useItemList(item?.id.toString()); ```

Comment: ```const { list } = item &&  useItemList(item?.id.toString());```  returns a warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot run the hook conditionally because **[React relies on the order in which Hooks are called](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation)**

React cannot track the state correctly if a hook is skipped

<s>An easy solution is to modify your `useItemList` code, if the argument is `undefined`, then don't call whatever is inside it.</s>

update: my solution is incorrect because the hook value is initial value, so it wont work.

this is the correct solution:

You should return a **memorized callback** from `useItemList` instead and run this callback in useEffect with `item` and that callback(optional) as dependency